# Split text from a certain word in OpenOffice

Tags: openoffice-calc

I have the following text in column A:

```
<p>De Buddha Lounge Zenju loungeset uit de new kubu wicker Zenju loungeset collectie in de kleurstelling new kubu wicker met zandkleurige kussens. Deze loungeset wordt compleet geleverd inclusief zandkleurige zit- en rugkussens. De Zenju loungeset bestaat uit twee bank elementen van 155x85xH64 cm, een Hoekelement van 85x85xH64 cm en een lounge hocker van 73x73xH40 cm. De totale afmeting van de set is 240x240 cm.</p><p><strong>Details:</strong><br />- Loungeset: 240x240<br />- Sofa L/R:155x85xH64<br />- Hoek: 85x85xH64<br />- Tafel: 73x73xH40</p>
```

My need is to split the text exactly by:

```
<p><strong>Details:
```

so that all the text up to this point is in column B, like this:

```
<p>De Buddha Lounge Zenju loungeset uit de new kubu wicker Zenju loungeset collectie in de kleurstelling new kubu wicker met zandkleurige kussens. Deze loungeset wordt compleet geleverd inclusief zandkleurige zit- en rugkussens. De Zenju loungeset bestaat uit twee bank elementen van 155x85xH64 cm, een Hoekelement van 85x85xH64 cm en een lounge hocker van 73x73xH40 cm. De totale afmeting van de set is 240x240 cm.</p>
```

We have a list that has exactly this format and need to split all the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data starts from `B1` cell of column `B`. Enter following formula to `C1` cell.

```
=MID(B1,SEARCH("strong",B1)-4,(SEARCH("/strong",B1)-1)-(SEARCH("strong",B1)-4))
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, with this input (and text in b1) I get a 508 error, any idea?

Comment: @Coen I tested the formula by inputting your data in `B1` cell then putting my formula in `C1` cell.

Comment: To avoid the 508 error, some versions require semicolons: `=MID(B1;SEARCH("strong";B1)-4;(SEARCH("/strong";B1)-1)-(SEARCH("strong";B1)-4))`

Comment: Semicolon are used some region. So, it necessary to which region the questioner are.

Comment: Yes, or depending on which version.

Comment: Well in my case I have version 4.1.3 and for now I said all the language settings on English (VS). I now took it with semicolons and then it gives the result: "<p><strong>Details:", so this already shows better results then before. What I actually need is all the text before this part, so the text till  <p><strong>Details. Do you also have an idea how to get that text? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For convenience, put this in cell D1:

```
<p><strong>Details:
```

Then use this formula, where the text is in cell A1:

```
=RIGHT(A1; LEN(A1)-SEARCH(D$1;A1)-LEN(D$1)+1)
```

The result:

```
</strong><br />- Loungeset: 240x240<br />- Sofa L/R:155x85xH64<br />- Hoek: 85x85xH64<br />- Tafel: 73x73xH40</p>
```

Documentation:

- https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_RIGHT_function
- https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_SEARCH_function

**EDIT**:

To get the text before it:

```
=LEFT(A1, SEARCH("<p><strong>Details:",A1)-1)
```

Result:

```
<p>De Buddha Lounge Zenju loungeset uit de new kubu wicker Zenju loungeset collectie in de kleurstelling new kubu wicker met zandkleurige kussens. Deze loungeset wordt compleet geleverd inclusief zandkleurige zit- en rugkussens. De Zenju loungeset bestaat uit twee bank elementen van 155x85xH64 cm, een Hoekelement van 85x85xH64 cm en een lounge hocker van 73x73xH40 cm. De totale afmeting van de set is 240x240 cm.</p>
```

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks for the solution, almost works, the only thing is that I don't need the text behind it so (</strong>), but the text before it (85x85xH64 cm en een lounge hocker van 73x73xH40 cm. De totale afmeting van de set is 240x240 cm.</p> etc). Is there a way to take the text before it instead the text behind it?

Answer (score 0):

Please select cells to be truncated, go to Edit > Find & Replace..., and under `Search for` enter:

```
<p><strong>Details:(.*)
```

leave `Replace with` blank but under `More Options` check `Current selection only` and `Regular expressions`, then `Replace All`.

This deletes the 'surplus' so you might want to work on a copy (say just copy ColumnA into ColumnB and work on that).